# If the fact that $f_y$ and $f_x$ are continuous can implies $f$ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y,Z$ be topological spaces, and $$f:X \times Y \rightarrow Z$$be a function, it induces 
$$f_y:X \rightarrow Z$$ where $f_y(x)=f(x,y)$, and 
$$f_x:Y \rightarrow Z$$ where $f_x(y)=f(x,y)$. Obvious that if continuous $f$ implies continuous $f_x$ and $f_y$, but my problem is:

If $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous for all $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, is $f$ continuous? (On metric space the answer is yes, but I don’t know it if $X,Y,Z$ are general topological spaces.)

Comment: Continuous respect which topology?

Comment: Why is the answer yes in metric spaces?

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka The universal property of the product says quite a different thing.

Comment: This is false even in $\mathbb R^2$: https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Separately_continuous_not_implies_continuous

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro You should answer, there is already a dubious “answer”.

Comment: Indeed my comment above is completely wrong. Sorry about that and thanks for pointing out my mistake. Unfortunately I cannot edit it anymore to mark it as wrong directly. Of course the universal property applies to the situation where the target space of the functions is a product, not the domain.

Answer (score 2):

This is false even in $\mathbb R^2$. A standard counterexample is the function 
$$
f(x, y)=\begin{cases} \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}, & (x, y)\ne (0,0), \\ 0, & (x, y)=(0,0).\end{cases}$$
Here, both $f(x, \cdot)$ and $f(\cdot, y)$ are continuous functions of $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ for all fixed values of $x$ and $y$, but 
$$
\lim_{t\to 0} f(t, t)=1\ne f(0,0), $$ 
so the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$.